# Ordering does not work on Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I want to different order on Desktop and on mobile,
Currently this is the order

On Med+ :

[image: Desktop]

On small:

[image: Mobile]

Desktop is good. This is the right position.
On mobile I want the picture to come below the button and the test.
I have tried order-sm-fist and order-sm-last and also order-1 until order-2 but nothing seems to change. Not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
    <section class="feature section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="heading">
                <h2>Try it now!</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 order-md-last">
                <img src="The image url is here"
                    class="" id="generated-monKey" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col md-2 order-md-1">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 order-md-first text-center">
                <p>Enter a Banano wallet address and press the "Generate monKey" button.</p>
                <br>
                <p>If you do not have a Banano wallet you can create one in BananoVault or simply generate a random Banano
                    wallet address.</p>
                <br>
                <div class="container">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-rounded" placeholder="Banano Address" maxlength="64" size="65">
                    <br>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <form>
                                <div class="checkbox col-md-6">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Accessories</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox col-md-6">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Background</label>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success form-rounded" border>Generate monKey</button>
                <br>
                <br> Monkeys are perfect for avatars. Click on the monKey image in order to download it.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

In this example I changed the md to first and last which means even on Desktop I should see the image on the right and the text on the left and yet nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML structure is so messy. Here are my 2 cents:

- No nested `container`
- `col`s should come right after `row`.
- What's up with the missing - on `col md-2`? And why do you need a column wrapping a `<br>`?

#### Cleaned up HTML structure

```
<section class="feature section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="heading"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 order-md-first">
                <img />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/144878/

Comment: Your code works as intended on jsfiddle but when I copy and paste it on my environment the monkey is on the right on desktop (medium). I really have no idea what's going on

Comment: @Randomizer: my fiddle is using the latest bootstrap 4.1.3. Yours is on 4.0.0. Is it possible for you to update to the latest or you have to stick with 4.0?